# If $A\approx_\varepsilon D$, where $D$ is diagonal, is $A$ already almost diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, nuclear-norm

Let $D$ and $A$ be symmetric positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices such that $\|D-A\|_1 \leq \varepsilon$, where $\|X\|_1 = \operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{X^*X})$. Moreover, let $D$ be diagonal.

Does there exist a unitary $U$ such that $UAU^* = D'$ (we diagonalize $A$) such that $\|D - D'\|_1$ is bounded in terms of $\varepsilon$?

Comment: You've asked a reasonable mathematical question, but you have not placed the problem in any context that would assist willing Readers to respond cogently.  Why does the problem interest you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that instead of $\|\cdot\|_1$ we can look at the Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A)}$ since
$$\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_1 \le \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$$
and these constants do not change boundedness/unboundedness.

Secondly, note that we can WLOG assume that $D$ is sorted in increasing order. Then $D'$ becomes $\Lambda(A)$, which is the matrix of eigenvalues of $A$ sorted in increasing order. We can always pass to such situation by looking at $P^*AP$ and $P^*DP$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix.

Thirdly, note that we can assume $\|A\|_2 \le 1$ and $\|D\|_2 \le 2$. Indeed, clearly we can assume $\varepsilon \in \langle 0,1\rangle$ and then
$$\|A-D\|_2 \le \varepsilon \implies \left\|\frac{A}{\|A\|_2}-\frac{D}{\|A\|_2}\right\|_2 \le \frac{\varepsilon}{\|A\|_2}, \quad\left\|\frac{D}{\|A\|_2}\right\|_2 \le 1+\varepsilon \le 2$$
which if we prove the claim for $\|A\|_2 \le 1$ and $\|D\|_2 \le 2$ will imply
$$\left\|\frac{\Lambda(A)}{\|A\|_2}-\frac{D}{\|A\|_2}\right\|_2 \le \frac{\varepsilon}{\|A\|_2} \implies \|\Lambda(A) - D\|_2\le \varepsilon.$$

Now our **claim** is that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a constant $M_\varepsilon >0$ such that for all positive semidefinite matrices $A,D$ with $\|A\|_2 \le 1, \|D\|_2 \le 2$ and $D$ is diagonal sorted in increasing order we have the implication
$$\|A-D\|_2 \le \varepsilon \implies \|\Lambda(A)-D\|_2 \le M_\varepsilon \varepsilon.$$

We prove the following **lemma**:

> Let $(A_n)_n$ and $(D_n)_n$ be sequences of positive semidefinite matrices where $\|A_n\|_2 \le 1, \|D_n\|_2 \le 2$ and $D_n$ is a diagonal matrix sorted in increasing order. Assume that $\|A_n - D_n\|_2 \to 0$. Then $\|\Lambda(A_n) - D_n\|_2 \to 0$.

Proof.

Assume $\|A_n-D_n\|_2 \to 0$. Denote $D(A_n)$ the diagonal matrix which consists of the diagonal of $A_n$. We have
$$\|A_n-D(A_n)\|_2^2 = \sum_{i\ne j} |(A_n)_{ij}|^2 \le \sum_{i\ne j} |(A_n)_{ij}|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n |(A_n)_{ii} - (D_n)_{ii}|^2 = \|A_n-D_n\|_2^2 \to 0.$$

Now recall the fact that the eigenvalues of a matrix are continuous functions of its entries. In particular, they are uniformly continuous on the closed ball of radius $2$. So we get
$$\|A_n-D(A_n)\|_2 \to 0 \implies \|\Lambda(A_n)-D(A_n)\|_2 = \|\Lambda(A_n)-\Lambda(D(A_n))\|_2 \to 0.$$
Finally, we have by triangle inequality
\begin{align}
\|\Lambda(A_n)- D_n\|_2 &=\|\Lambda(A_n)-D(A_n)\|_2 + \|D(A_n)-D_n\|_2 \\
&\le \|\Lambda(A_n)-D(A_n)\|_2 + \|A_n-D_n\|_2\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0
\end{align}
which proves the lemma.

Now assume that our **claim** from above is false. This means there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ and sequences of positive semidefinite matrices $(A_n)_n$ and $(D_n)_n$ such that $\|A_n\| \le 1$, $\|D_n\| \le 2$, $D_n$ is diagonal sorted in increasing order such that
$$\|A_n - D_n\|_2 \le\varepsilon, \quad \text{ but }\quad \|\Lambda(A_n)-D_n\|_2 \ge n^2\varepsilon.$$

Consider sequences $\left(\frac1nA_n\right)_n$ and $\left(\frac1nD_n\right)_n$. These satisfy the assumptions of our **lemma** since
$$\left\|\frac1nA_n - \frac1nD_n\right\|_2 = \frac1n \|\Lambda(A_n)-D_n\|_2 \le\frac{\varepsilon}n \to 0$$
so $$n\varepsilon \le \left\|\frac1n\Lambda(A_n) - \frac1nD_n\right\|_2 = \left\|\Lambda\left(\frac1n A_n\right) - \frac1nD_n\right\|_2\to 0$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore, our **claim** is true.

Comment: About the last line, we can always choose $U$ such that $D'$ is the correct permutation of eigenvalues, right? I'm only asking for the existence of one $D'$ and it seems like I have it here. Or did I misunderstand your point?

Comment: @user1936752 Yes, you can choose $U$ to obtain any permutation of eigevalues in $D'$. My point is that there is no permutation of eigenvalues such that the respective $D'$ is close to $D$. This disproves the existence of such $D'$.

Comment: @user1936752 If by "correct permutation" you mean the sorted one i.e. $D' = \operatorname{diag}(1,2,3)$, then we have
$$\|D-D'\|_1 = \|\operatorname{diag}(2\sin^2t,0,2\cos^2 t-2)\|_1 = 2\sin^2 t + 2 - 2\cos^2 t = 2-2\cos(2t) \ge 1.$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. $2 - 2\cos(2t)\rightarrow 0 \leq 1$ in the limit $t\rightarrow 0$ no?

Comment: @user1936752 You are right. I'm sorry, I've made a mistake.

Comment: @user1936752 I know I'm clutching at straws here but have a look at my new attempt.

Comment: @mechanodroid what if OP wanted a bound independent of $n$?

Comment: @mathworker21 OP should have made the statement "bounded in terms of $\varepsilon$" more precise in general.